# Concorde installation : need to link an lp solver to use this function

Tags: c++, cygwin, configure, automake, np-complete

I'be been trying to install the TSP solver of Concorde on Cygwin, but I'm facing some difficulties :
I downloaded Qsopt on the official website, the two files in the "Cygwin" part, and put them in /home/qs. Then, I download concorde, gunzip it, tar it, so I have /home/concorde. I go in this folder and type "./configure --with-qsopt=/home/qs". Everything seems to go well, so I type "make", and this is what I've got (several lines like this) :

```
/home/concorde/LP/lpqsopt.c:645 : undefined reference « QSget_param »
/home/concorde/LP/lpqsopt.c:674 : undefined reference « QSset_param »
/home/concorde/LP/lpqsopt.c:650 : undefined reference « QSset_param »
/home/concorde/LP/lpqsopt.c:655 : undefined reference « QSopt_dual »
```

Do you have an idea on how to solve this ? I didn't find anything on the web.
(I 've got automake 1.15)

The command that produce this error seems to be :

```
gcc -fPIC -O2 -g  -o concorde concorde.o tsp.a ../PQ/pq.a ../VERIFY/verify.a ../LOCALCUT/localcut.a   ../TINY/tiny.a ../LINKERN/linkern.a   ../EDGEGEN/edgegen.a ../KDTREE/kdtree.a     ../FMATCH/fmatch.a ../UTIL/util.a ../BIGGUY/bigguy.a     ../CUT/cut.a ../HELDKARP/heldkarp.a ../LP/lp.a ../COMBS/combs.a /home/qs/qsopt.a -liberty -lm ../LP/lp.a(lpqsopt.o)
```

And then as you see, the errors seems to come from LP

Thanks a lot,
Djazouli

Comment: Can you post the actual command that is failing? It would be easier to figure the problem. I could find a git repository that *could* be what you're trying to build, but I'm not sure which part of the build tree is failing.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late response, I edit my post, I hope this is what you wanted !
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

So I found the source code and it looks like the problem is in [TSP/Makefile.in](https://github.com/mburke13/concorde/blob/master/TSP/Makefile.in#L58).

The problem is that the parameters given to the link editor (`ld`) are positional: object files (and convenience static archives) need to come before the libraries they link to.

In this case there is a second instance of `../LP/lp.a(lpqsopt.o)` being passed at the end, and given nothing to link against. I'm not sure where that is coming from though. The build system is quite a mouthful to figure out where the error comes from.